# JavaScript not executed when it has Magento_Customer/js/customer-data dependencia in define

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs, jquery, customer-data

I have a JS file like this:

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'matchMedia',
        'text!ajaxcart/template/modal-slide.html',
        'text!ajaxcart/template/modal-popup.html',
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
        'Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'mage/translate'
    ], function($, _, mediaCheck, _slideTpl, _popupTpl, customerData) {
...
    }
```

But for some reason, it is not entered into the code in **function** until I remove *"Magento_Customer/js/customer-data"*. I mean, if I change it to this:

```
define([
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'matchMedia',
        'text!ajaxcart/template/modal-slide.html',
        'text!ajaxcart/template/modal-popup.html',
        //'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
        'Magento_Catalog/product/view/validation',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal',
        'mage/translate'
    ], function($, _, mediaCheck, _slideTpl, _popupTpl/*, customerData*/) {
...
    }
```

It works fine, except in the part of the code where I need the **customerData** variable that returns an obvious error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: customerData is not defined.

But if I keep it as in the start, all file is ignored and not executed. I don't know why the reference Magento_Customer/js/customer-data is causing this problem. I don't see any error in the browser console or log. Any idea?

**UPDATE:** I detected this same error happened with another JS file but with **mage/cookies** dependency:

```
require([
        "jquery",
        "Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal",
        "mage/cookies",
        "jquery/jquery.cookie",
        'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer'
    ],function($, modal,cookie,jscookie,customer) {
      ...
    }
```

Same behavior, if I remove *mage/cookies*, it works, but when is present, the code is not running.